# #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server / Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, password-recovery

I use PHP/MySQL in Ubuntu 13.

To reduce the size of ibdata1, i followed this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/what-is-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql and make necessary changes as told in the answer.

I did set a password for phpmyadmin when I installed it. Now after restarting mysql, and when I try to login into phpmyadmin with my password, an error is thrown out.

**#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server**

**Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.**

Can anyone please tell me, where I went wrong. I followed the steps correctly and I am sure about that. I just wanna login into phpmyadmin. Tell me how can i reset my password?

Comment: Have you checked the password in the config file? is it correct?

Comment: how to access the config file? Is it my.cnf file???

Comment: No, that is the mysql config file. You need to view the `config.inc.php` in the `phpmyadmin` directory - See - http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/phpMyAdmin_configuration_file.

Comment: there ain't no passwords set in config.inc.php in phpmyadmin. Acctually I've got 2 files with that name. One in var/lib/phpmyadmin/ directory and that file is empty & another one in etc/phpmyadmin/ directory (i think that's the file you are talking about) and it ain't go no password in it.

Comment: You need to either amend the config file to reflect your settings or reinstall the phpmyadmin - See - http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.